# How to make sure Rabbit MQ messages are sent with delivery mode "persistent" with Paramore Brighter

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq, brighter

I am using Paramore Brighter.Net for consuming Rabbit Message Queue. I want to set the delivery mode of the message to "persistent". I did no get any property in brighter namespace that can internally set the rabbit mq delivery mode.

RMQMessageGateway class has IModel reference which internally has CreateBasicProperties method which i can use to set the delivery mode property. However the property's access specifier is protected and I am unable to set it. Kindly help[image].

Comment: Any chance you can post the _code_ instead of a picture?

Comment: the code is from Brighter https://github.com/BrighterCommand/Brighter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a clone of their code and modify it since their [license](https://github.com/BrighterCommand/Brighter/blob/master/LICENCE.txt) model is [MIT](https://tldrlegal.com/license/mit-license).  `Channel` is actually set inside the `ConnectToBroker` method so you can make your changes there.

If you don't want to modify their code, you can derive a new class from [`RMQMessageGateway`](https://github.com/BrighterCommand/Brighter/blob/master/src/Paramore.Brighter.MessagingGateway.RMQ/RMQMessageGateway.cs) and `override` `ConnectToBroker`.  Then do whatever post actions there such as setting the delivery mode.